# Use WSRR web service outside a web application

Tags: web-services, wsrr

I have a web application mostly written by others based on JSF 2, Mybatis, Spring 3 and tens of other libraries, running on Weblogic, it works and now I have to create a distinct command line application to schedule the running of some tasks already present in the web app.

I added a class with a `main` method in order to maintain only one codebase with a different build process to generate an executable `JAR` instead of a `WAR`. Using Spring's `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` I managed to recreate the web application context, access the database beans and use them, but I'm stuck with a WSRR call which fails.

The commands:

```
GraphQuery graphQuery = 
                (GraphQuery)DataFactory.INSTANCE.create(TypeConstants.SR_URI, TypeConstants.TYPE_GRAPHQUERY);
            graphQuery.setQueryExpression("/WSRR/GenericObject[@CFT_APPLIC='DS" + param + "']");
```

fail with a long stack, having the root exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:960)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.resources.ProjectResourceBundle$Context.loadBundle(ProjectResourceBundle.java:474)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.resources.ProjectResourceBundle.getBundle(ProjectResourceBundle.java:372)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.resources.ProjectResourceBundle.getBundle(ProjectResourceBundle.java:341)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.resources.MessagesConstants.<clinit>(MessagesConstants.java:93)
```

I found that some classes and configurations are provided at runtime by the application server, and have no idea about how to replace them outside the application server.

The [IBM redbook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247386.pdf) says (pages 120-121) that is possible to access a web service using a Java client, but requires a suitable `EJB` runtime.

How can I replicate needed EJB parameters outside the application server? I tried to use the Eclipse debugger to follow the execution of the application and extract them, but it fails, probably because the classes are loaded by Weblogic classloader.